# jupyter notebook password usage

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I would like to run a public jupyter notebook server. I only want few people able to use it. I see on Jupyter documentation to set the password but did not set the ssl items.

After setting the password:

1. Everything is as before setting the password, I can do whatever i please like before so can everybody.
2. I want user able to have own account password to use the notebook web.

Anyone having same view able to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Jupyter is not designed to support this out of the box.

One possible solution would be to put your Jupyter instance behind an apache web server:

1. configure jupyter to listen only on 127.0.0.1.  This is the default configuration, but it sounds as if you've already changed this.
2. configure apache with the appropriate authentication modules (LDAP, local passwords, basic auth, etc).
3. configure apache's mod_proxy to pass connections from the apache server to jupyter on localhost.

Unfortunately, steps 2 and 3 are beyond the scope of what I can cover here since it depends on your OS, version of apache, and other aspects of your environment.  It may be enough for me to point out that this is no different than putting apache in front of another web application server such as Jetty or tomcat, which is documented extensively on other sites on the internet.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Apache